# Why does my Morea site look OK locally but not when published?

Tags: morea-framework

When I am running my Morea site locally, the page displays fine, but once I publish it, the formatting is all messed up.  It seems the CSS files are not being loaded. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason for this is that you forgot to edit the baseurl property in the master/src/_config.yml file.  By default, the line looks like:

```
baseurl: /core
```

You need to change this value to the name of your repo. So, if you site is named ics632_fall2015, you need to edit baseurl to:

```
baseurl: /ics632_fall2015
```

The baseurl property is ignored when running locally, which is why the site displays correctly in that situation.

As of summer 2017, another user ran into this problem and the solution was to update their morea scripts to the current version. So if your baseurl is set correctly, a second thing to check is that you are using the current version of the Morea scripts.